# Query Performance and Single Quotes

Tags: oracle

We have a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE "ABC"(
"ID" NUMBER (18, 0) NOT NULL,
"ID2" VARCHAR2(15 char) NULL,
"VERSION" VARCHAR2(30 char) NULL,
"TIMESTAMP" DATE  NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "PK_ABC" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);

ALTER TABLE ABC ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_ABC_ID2_VERSION UNIQUE(ID2, VERSION);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX1_ABC ON ABC 
(
    ID2, 
    VERSION
);



CREATE INDEX "IDX2_ABC" ON ABC
(
                VERSION ASC,
                ID2 ASC,
                TIMESTAMP ASC
);
```

say there is a high volume of data on the same table. Would you be able to help conclude which Query from below would have better performance and why

First query:

```
SELECT ID, ID2, VERSION, TIMESTAMP 
FROM ABC WHERE ID2=123 
  AND VERSION =54321
```

Second query:

```
SELECT ID, ID2, VERSION, TIMESTAMP 
FROM ABC 
WHERE ID2='123' 
  AND VERSION ='54321'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
SQL> explain plan for SELECT ID, ID2, VERSION, TIMESTAMP FROM ABC WHERE ID2=123 AND VERSION =54321;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1033171814

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |   116 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| ABC  |     1 |   116 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("ID2")=123 AND TO_NUMBER("VERSION")=54321)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

17 rows selected.
```

As you can see, this is bad, because you have number literals but the type of the columns is `varchar2`. The columns are implicitly converted to number with `TO_NUMBER`. Becasue of this, the index can not be used, as the index contains columns `ID2` and `VERSION`, and not `TO_NUMBER(ID2)` and `TO_NUMBER(VERSION)`. A function-based index can be used in such a case, but that is not the right solution here.

2)

```
SQL> explain plan for SELECT ID, ID2, VERSION, TIMESTAMP FROM ABC WHERE ID2='123' AND VERSION ='54321';

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1869257811

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                    |     1 |   116 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ABC                |     1 |   116 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | CK_ABC_ID2_VERSION |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID2"='123' AND "VERSION"='54321')
```

With proper types, everything works expected, the index can be used.

It is not a matter of single quotes, but a matter of using proper datatypes, so 2) is better.

Comment: Thank you!! Just thinking out loud, would it be able to configure Oracle to not convert the column but rather convert the value??

Comment: @rrrohanb It is not the column vs value, it is `number` vs. `varchar2`. As far as I know, when comparing `number` to `varchar2`, Oracle always converts `varchar2` to `number`, and I do not know of any configuration option related to this.

Answer (score 0):

## Code Review

`ID2` and `VERSION` are defined as `VARCHAR2`.

SQL 1 uses a `NUMBER` data type for the right hand side.  Implicit Conversion is occurring.

Relying on the outcome of Implicit Conversion is considered to be "bad practice". Use SQL 2.

Also, SQL 1 could fail as soon as you have row that matches

```
WHERE VERSION='0.99-beta'
```

## Performance Notes

As far as performance, I see no reason why the Plan should be different.  Any actual difference in performance would be due to data type conversion and would be measured in [Jiffies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_(time)).

Comment: Plans will be different because during implicit conversion "When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value" (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214) .